# how I get the name of current user logged in angular 4?

Tags: angular

My Angular4 application should get the current logged in user How can I get the user name in to my app.

```html
 Signin(email: string, password:string ): Observable<boolean> {
    
   // console.log(info);
    var data = JSON.stringify({email: email, password: password});
    return this.http.post(this.server +"user/signin" , data, this.options).map((response: Response) => {
      // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
      let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
      if (token) {
          // set token property
          this.token = token;

          // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ email:email , token: token }));

          // return true to indicate successful login
          return true;
      } else {
          // return false to indicate failed login
          return false;
      }
  });
    }
```

in the login component.ts

```html
  onSignin() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.authService.Signin(this.model.email, this.model.password)
        .subscribe(result => {
            if (result === true) {
                // login successful
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
            } else {
                // login failed
                this.error = 'Username or password is incorrect';
                this.loading = false;
            }
            
        });
```

Comment: Place the username in your token and decode it when you get it.

Comment: how i can place it in the token without use it in the login

Comment: Do you know how tokens work ?

Comment: just a littel idea

Comment: They are encrypted payloads : you chose what is inside. So put the username in it, and decode it with a library. You want some help on that ?

Comment: yesif you can plz

Comment: **[This link](https://jwt.io/)** will explain to you how JWT works, and let you play with it. **[This library](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt)** will help you decode the token on the front-end side. I can't help you about the back-end though, but that should be a good start !

Comment: thank you a lot and i use in the backend php laravel

Comment: Then **[this link](https://medium.com/@mosesesan/tutorial-5-how-to-build-a-laravel-5-4-jwt-authentication-api-with-e-mail-verification-61d3f356f823)** should help you building a JWT authentication. Good luck !

Comment: I assume the email is unique, can you use it to fetch the current user on the server -- which should have the username -- Then add that username to the token as @trichetriche has said.

Comment: I am very grateful to you :)

Comment: @FelixToo ok this is an idea and i will try to do it thank you

Comment: when i get the currentUser and decoded i jsut can get my email how i can from this email fetch my username

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you are storing in the user email (which i assume is your username) in localstorage under `currentUser`.

So to get that email you would do the following in whatever component or service you require to get the information.

To do it via a service:

```
getUsername() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).email;
}
```

To get it directly in a component:

```
username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).email;

// or if you are using the service method above then in your component do following:

username = this.myService.getUsername();
```

And thats it.